# Renaming .doc or .docx with python according to a text from the document

Tags: python, rename, docx, file-rename, doc

I have an issue regarding changing a .doc or .docx filename according to a certain text inside the document.

I have been able to establish this function with .txt files. With the following code:

```
import os
import re
pat = "ID number(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)"         #This is for the text to be found in the file
ext = '.txt'                                #Type of file the python is searching for
mydir = ''  #Path or directory where python is doing its magic

for arch in os.listdir(mydir):              
    archpath = os.path.join(mydir, arch)
    with open(archpath) as f:
        txt = f.read()
    s = re.search(pat, txt)
    if s is None:
        continue
    name = s.group(1)
    newpath = os.path.join(mydir, name)
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.rename(archpath, newpath + ext)
```

Anyone have any takes on this?

Comment: you need to explain a little better. Here you are showing how you would do it if you where parsing a text file? You want to know how to parse a doc or doc ex and look for this regular expression?

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed enough. What i want to be able to do is to have a doc or docx file opened and looked for a certain value that it will rename the file to and save it.

Comment: DOC files are not text files; just plain `open` is fine for reading plain text, but you need a parser for DOC format to do this. Look for the `python-docx` module or equivalent to read Microsoft's file formats. (I'm not sure whether it can also read the legacy `.doc` format. Maybe you need a separate module for that, or black magic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found. The issue was on my end. I was trying to find a value. But what i needed was to specify an cell. Since the value was in a table.

Here is the result:

```
import os
import re
import sys
pat = "(\d+)"       #Type of string/value that is being renamed
ext = '.docx'       #Type of file the python is searching for
mydir = ''  #Path or directory where python is doing its magic

from docx import Document
for arch in os.listdir(mydir):
    archpath = os.path.join(mydir, arch)
    document = Document(archpath)
    table = document.tables[0]
    s = re.search(pat,table.cell(1,2).text)
    if s is None:
        continue
    name = s.group(1)
    newpath = os.path.join(mydir, name)
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.rename(archpath, newpath + ext)
print (newpath + ext)
input("Press Enter to exit")
```

It needs to be taken in account that this method is only usable with .docx files that are usable with word 2007 and later. Since python-docx does not work with earlier versions or .doc files

So my next project is to get implemented an converter from .doc to .docx

Thank you for everyones participation.

Comment: use [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) `antiword my.doc > my.docx`

Answer (score 1):

you will need [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from docx import Document
for arch in os.listdir(mydir):              
    archpath = os.path.join(mydir, arch)
    document = Document(archpath)
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        s = re.search(pat, para.text)
    if s is None:
        continue
    name = s.group(1)
    newpath = os.path.join(mydir, name)
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.rename(archpath, newpath+'docx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now it seems i have come against a different problem. When trying to run this it states i do not have the correct module. Even though i did install python-docx?

Comment: Fixed it by using VENV. But now theres this issue : File "site-packages\docx\api.py, line 25 in Document . Several one of these and then in the end KeyError: "no relationship of type 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' in collection" Is there something of with my source files format?

Comment: you may have to post your doc file somewhere

Comment: I found my issue. It is that its a table. So i have to use docx.document.table to get the information. But for some reason it is only looking at the bottom row of the table so im still trying to figure it out